# BLE writeValue to peripheral

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am having trouble to write values to a BLE device. I translated this:

```
NSLog(@"Writing value for characteristic %@", interestingCharacteristic);
    [peripheral writeValue:dataToWrite forCharacteristic:interestingCharacteristic
        type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

to Swift:

```
peripheral.writeValue("Writing value for characteristic", forCharacteristic: interestingCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse)
```

But I get the error `Use of unresolved identifier 'CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse'`

I am new to iOs programming and tried manyfold ways to make it work but it just wouldn't happen. Can you help me please.

Comment: you've kind of mixed up the NSLog call and the actual writeValue message being passed. check the doc here: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBPeripheral/writeValue:forCharacteristic:type:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have combined the `NSLog` statement and the `writeValue` method into some sort of bizarre mashup.

What you want is

```
println("Writing value for characteristic \(interestingCharacteristic)")
peripheral.writeValue(dataToWrite, forCharacteristic:interestingCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)
```

Comment: thx, with:
peripheral.writeValue(data: "01", forCharacteristic: interestingCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)
I get the error: Extra argument 'type' in call

Comment: Correct.  Look at my answer.  The first parameter is anonymous and it is NSData, not a string

Comment: ahh okay, now I understand the error message. Also thought that NSString is subclass of NSData. Thx again =)